# NSData to Swift Integer

Tags: integer, swift, nsdata

I have an NSMutableData, i make subdata with its method for getting the exact bytes of the integer that i will create. But somehow i can not convert that bytes into integer. It seems okay when i am debugging i see the subdata value as "<04 00 00 00>" -which i need to convert-.

```
    var lengthData:NSData = buffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(12,4))
    var length:Int = //Conversion which must be done from lengthData
    var dataPart:NSData = buffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(16, length))
```

I tried to convert the lengthData to NSString and get the integer value of it but no-success. Can you please help about this conversion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read required amount of bytes into the primitive type variable just by passing it's pointer to the `.getBytes(...)` function:

```
var length: Int = 0
data.getBytes(&length, range: NSRange(location: 12, length: 4))
```

Comment: This'd be the way, although it's slightly more 'Swifty' to use `NSRange(location: 12, length: 4)` rather than the old `NSMakeRange` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to convert it but not directly. First i create an array with length 1(i know that it will be 1 element in array), then i copy the NSData value into that array then take the first element. It is like:

```
    var lengthData:NSData = buffer.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(12,4))
    var array = Int[](count: 1, repeatedValue: 1)
    lengthData.getBytes(&array, length:1)
    var length:Int = array[0]
```

This helped me but any direct conversions will be appreciated too.